# Joik - traditional Sami songs from northern Sweden and Finland

Tags: voice, improvisation, performing

I have some questions about the traditional Sami singing, **Joiken**, which is practiced in the northern parts of Sweden, Finland and Norway.

I learned that you don't joik *about something*, but you *joik something*, i.e. express your feelings and make them appear in front of you and the audience - which sounds a similar to the alpine "Jodeln".

What I want to know for a Joik is

- are syllables tied to certain meanings like sadness, joy, love, animals?
- are there any syllables that are prefered over others, such as ley-la, o-ley - or can anything be used that sounds right at the moment of performing?
- does the concept of a major or minor scale have any meaning like in Western music e.g.minor/sad, major/happy?
- is a Joik purely improvised i.e. is it possible/impossible to do it again another time in the same way, other than recording it on a CD? In other words: does a performer try to remember that Joik and try to do it the same way the next time?

Comment: A recording that might be of interest: [Pseudo-Yoik](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJwO3uHIgNc), by Jaakko Mänteyjärvi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for your question - it introduced me to the idea of "Joik", and since I have admired the Sami for years, my world is a little bit richer for now having heard some of it...

As far as answering goes - I have a Finnish friend that was good enough to reply to your questions, and I include her words below - her perspective is fascinating, and a good addition to material that I could find elsewhere on the net.

> "I came across the yoik in research I did on Sami traditions and their
>   reindeer husbandry. A yoik, as far as I understand it, is not a song
>   in the way that we would describe or analyze something musically.
>   There are no rules on notes, intonations,
>   minor/major/key/sharp/flat/etc. And, one does not sing a yoik, or
>   create one, but a 'yoik' is an 'identifier'. For instance, in
>   traditional animal husbandry for the Sami, each reindeer is called by
>   his/her yoik that the herder sings. The animals come to their yoik
>   when they hear it. In the same way, a person develops their 'yoik' for
>   a way to articulate who and what they are in the world. These change
>   depending on their circumstances, what they experience... and,
>   importantly, do not contain actual words, just sounds. A Finnish folk
>   group, The Girls of Angeli, have made the 'yoik' popularized, and it
>   is for this reason that people somehow equate it to an actual song.
>   (info on them here:
>   http://www.answers.com/topic/the-new-voice-of-the-north)
>
> My understanding is that while it can feel and sound like a song, it
>   should not be understood as such. That would be like calling what
>   Buddhist singing bowls do exact notes. No, it is more like an aura, an
>   energy of tonal inflection that paints itself into a representation of
>   another physical being. A tonal ghost, if you will.
>
> Oh, and not much has been studied on tonal inflection related to
>   emotion in other cultures that I know of, apart from some interesting
>   work in psychology on emotion words (linguistics). While the western
>   mind might associate a minor note to sadness, this does not mean a
>   non-western mind would do the same. Sami, and their Northern European
>   counterparts, cannot be classified 'Western' in the way that the
>   American public can claim it. Culturally, even the Northern countries
>   are complete different beasts from each other. :) And, 'positive' and
>   'negative' emotion words are also subjective, based on environment,
>   meaning, cultural context. A 'negative' word in our culture is exactly
>   what is helpful and considerate in another."

Hope this helps!